# '++' is deprecated: it will be removed in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

Estoy migrando una clase a Swift 3 y me muestra el error: **'++' is deprecated: it will be removed in Swift 3.**

Este es el codigo:

```
column = column >= (numberOfColumns - 1) ? 0 : ++column
```

El problema es en ++column.

Comment: en este url https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0004-remove-pre-post-inc-decrement.md   se encuentran opciones y la explicacion de la razon para eliminarlo

Comment: Gracias por el link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es correcto, el operador `++` no se puede usar más. En tu caso, de todas formas, no lo necesitabas...

Primero estabas incrementando el valor de `column` al hacer `++column`, y luego le estabas asignando ese valor a la variable `column` (lo que no tenía ningún efecto).

Lo deberías escribir así:

```
column = column >= (numberOfColumns - 1) ? 0 : column+1
```

Comment: Me soluciono el error. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

`++` fue deprecado en Swift 3, la solución que veo para esa linea es la siguiente:

```
column = column >= (numberOfColumns - 1) ? 0 : column+1
```

Comment: Al poner +=1, igual sigue apareciendo error.

Comment: Debe ser "column+1".